# Django App Configuration Options

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, caption

I am making an app to allow a user to control a rotation of banners on their site. I have all the image stuff working. A user can upload images and captions and what not. What I am wondering is, how I would achieve some sort of configuration portion to where the user could determine how many images they want and which ones they want. So that when the view goes to the DB to get the images and the info, it is getting just the right amount and the right ones.

I suppose I could do this with a single table that is a sort of configuration table, or perhaps a single file that is edited through the admin to set config options, but maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: Please keep the evangelism out of here - it's not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: Hi Daniel, It is never my intent to offend anyone, nor am i trying to convert you. I am just a joyful man and sometimes I can't help but say things about Jesus. I do thank you for your contribution to so many people. It seems as though you have a real passion to help people write gret code. Thanks also for your care for this forum, you have taken up a responisbility and that is wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you need by making a model to hold extra information that is then related to a user. Check out [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) in the Django documentation, and it should get you going.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, this will be very useful to me.